# Multiple Views in One Template

Tags: django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have two views:

1 - DisplayInfo  (displays information from User Table)
2 - AddTopics    (Adds data into the Topics Table)

and one template:

1- Test.html

--

The problem I have is, I can't display the stuff I want from both views on the template, only one of them.  I have associated both views in URLs.py,  but the urls.py will read the first instance rather than both, so only one view gets displayed on the template, and ignores the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I have figured out a temporary solution.  I have used a iFrame to load a second template into my main template.  It by far **not** the best solution, but it's better than having no solution.

I'll keep the question up here, just in case someone else has the same problem, or if another has a better solution.

Thanks